# How to display the result of adding two counters in sharepoint 2010 webpart?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, sharepoint-list

I took some code for displaying the content of a sharepoint 2010 list in a webpart based on a CAML query and modified it to display the same thing from two lists instead of one in a table. Now I want to further modify the code in order to get the number of incomplete tasks across both lists. to do that I added counters to the loops that populate the table and stored the result in another variable c. Now, the table is populated fine and does what i want it to do, but the value of the variable c is not displayed... can anyone help? I'll be really thankfull.
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;

namespace SharePoint365.WebParts.OutstandingTasks
{
  [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
  public class OutstandingTasks : WebPart
  {
    int a; // HERE (1)
    int b; // HERE (1)
    int c; // HERE (1)
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
      /*int a;
      int b;
      int c;*/
      SPList taskList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["test list 1"];
      SPList taskList1 = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["test list 2"];

      SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
      query.Query = "<Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='Status' />";
                   +"<Value Type='Text'>Completed</Value></Neq></Where>";
      query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Status'/>";

      SPListItemCollection tasks = taskList.GetItems(query);
      SPListItemCollection tasks1 = taskList1.GetItems(query);
      string htmlTable = "<table border='1'>";  
      htmlTable += "<tr><td>Title</td><td>Status</td></tr>";  

      foreach (SPListItem aTask in tasks)  
      {  
        htmlTable += string.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>",
                       aTask["Title"], aTask["Status"]);
        a++;  // HERE (2)
      }
      foreach (SPListItem aTask in tasks1)
      {
        htmlTable += string.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>",
                       aTask["Title"], aTask["Status"]);
        b++; // HERE (3)
      }

      htmlTable += "</table>";  

      c = a + b;            // HERE (4)
      Console.WriteLine(c); // HERE (4)

      LiteralControl tableControl = new LiteralControl(htmlTable);  
      this.Controls.Add(tableControl); 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use Console.WriteLine to display c. You need to use a LiteralControl like you do with your other strings:

```
c = a + b;
LiteralControl totals = new LiteralControl(c.ToString());
this.Controls.Add(totals);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rickard, your help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you got the answer but. Your approach to filter two table is wrong. You need to use 
**SPSiteDataQuery** Object which we can use to query multiple sharepoint list.

SPContext.Current.Web.GetSiteData(SPSiteDataQuery Obj);

Follow below link to know more about it
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx